# conversion from double to unsigned int

Tags: c++, math, floating-point

I am facing a problem with the conversion of value from Double to int. I try to run the following code :

```
int main()
{
    double val_d= 6.25e-05;
    cout << (1/val_d) << endl;
    unsigned int val_ui = (unsigned int ) (1/val_d);
    cout << val_ui << endl;
}
```

conversion from double to int may remove decimal part but integer part should remain
as it is ?

The output i get is : 
16000
15999

so why is the o/p different here ?
This is happening only on fedora. On windows and Ubuntu it works fine. ( Both output are 16000)

I tweaked the above code and got the following results :

```
int main()
{
  double val_d= 6.25e-05;
  cout << (1/val_d) << endl;
  double val_intermediate =  (1/val_d) ;
  cout << val_intermediate << endl;
  unsigned int val_ui = (unsigned int ) val_intermediate;
  cout << val_ui << endl;

}
```

NEW OUTPUT is
16000
16000
16000

Comment: What does it output? And what is your *expected* output? Isn't this what you get : http://ideone.com/0eXhl

Comment: I don't actually see a question here. Is something going wrong? What is the problem you are facing? Is your code not working as you'd expect?

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is to me. Isn't it working as you expect? What is it doing and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: It seems to behave as expected: http://ideone.com/VkTov gives 16000 for both outputs.

Comment: Standard answer for this and many other similar misunderstandings about floating point arithmetic: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I get 16000 and 15999 also using Embarcadero C++ Builder. What compiler are you using?

Comment: <strike>Compiler implementations. GCC shows 1600 for all cases. [Demo 1](http://ideone.com/NMW2C) [Demo 2](http://ideone.com/LXHm6)</strike>

Oh only in fedora. I'm not sure. What CPU and what virtual machine are you using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the source text “6.25e-05” is interpreted as a decimal numeral and converted to double, it is not exactly representable, because floating-point values have limited precision, and each bit has a value that is a power of two, not a decimal digit. The IEEE 754 double-precision value that is nearest to 6.25e-5 is 6.25000000000000013010426069826053208089433610439300537109375e-05, or, in hexadecimal floating-point, 0x1.0624dd2f1a9fcp-14.

When the reciprocal of this is taken, the exact mathematical result is again not exactly representable, so it must be rounded again. The nearest double-precision value is 16000 or 0x1.f4p+13.

The C++ standard allows implementations to evaluate floating-point expressions with more precision than the nominal type requires. Some implementations use extended precision, notably Intel's 80-bit floating-point type, which has a 64-bit significand. (Regular double precision has a 53-bit significand.) In this extended precision, the reciprocal is 0xf.9fffffffffffe89p+10 or 15999.99999999999966693309261245303787291049957275390625.

Obviously, when the extended-precision result is truncated to an integer, the result is 15999.

Rounding the long-double result to double would produce 16000. (You can do this with an explicit cast to double; you do not need to assign the intermediate value to a double object.)

Answer (score 6):

difference in **rounding**.

1. (1/val_d) - double is rounded **to the nearest possible number** that
   can be represented with double precision; (ex.: 3.6999999999999999
   == 3.7)
2. (unsigned int ) (1/val_d) - when casting to int decimal part is
   truncated, that results on **rounding down** (ex.: int(3.6) == 3

Answer (score 1):

Converting a floating-point value to an integral value removes the fractional part, provided the result can be represented in the integral type (i.e. the value isn't too large to fit). Inserting into a stream **rounds** the value, which can produce a different result.